# What kind of noun is 'splurge'?

Tags: nouns, articles, word-usage

I was reading a grammar book the other day, it was mentioned to omit articles "before names of substances and abstract nouns (i.e uncountable nouns)."

The nouns *splurge* and *howler* are abstract nouns I believe. However in the following sentences we have to use articles before the above mentioned nouns in order to convey the actual meaning.

> Spending 1.5 Lakhs on a computer is *a splurge*.
>
> How did he fail to score from that position? That was *a howler*!

Are the given nouns abstract nouns in the first place? If yes then what is the rule for using articles before them ?

Comment: Why do you believe *[splurge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/splurge)* and *[howler](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/howler)* are abstract nouns?

Comment: The advice to omit articles "before names of substances and abstract nouns (i.e., uncountable nouns)" is nonsense. Ignore it. It depends on context. "Love", e.g., is an abstract noun. Saying "He loved her with **a** love so strong" concretizes that particular love. Saying "**The** love he had for alcohol..." also concretizes that particular love. If you want to talk about _love_ in the abstract, then say "Love is wonderful, the second time around": no article.

Comment: I don't accept the term 'concretises' here - your switch rather 'particularises'.  The _love_ is still just as undetectable (directly) by sight, hearing, smell, taste or touch. Doesn't JL call this simply 'countification'?

Comment: @Edwin: It's as concrete as any other feeling or anything else detected by one of the senses. As Jon Hanna says below: "While you can't point to a splurge ('the splurge is beside the fridge' for example), **it counts as a thing** rather than [an] abstract[ion]. And it is countable." Perhaps Prof Lawler has called this _countification_, but he & I agree that the terminology is there to help us talk about things, not to explain things. The verb [reify](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reify?show=0&t=1357909038) comes to mind [reify2](http://thesaurus.com/browse/reify?s=b).

Comment: Then, too, there's the **particularizing** of the abstraction _love_ by calling it _[agape NOUN](http://thesaurus.com/browse/agape?s=b)_ or "affection, altruism, amity, attachment, benevolence, benignity, bountifulness, bounty, caritas, clemency, fellow feeling, generosity, goodness, goodwill, grace, humaneness, humanity, indulgence, kindliness, lenity, love, magnanimity, mercy, tenderheartedness"

Comment: @Bill: I haven't been able to pin down **the** definition of 'abstract noun', but the consensus I'm finding is 'not immediately discernable by the five _physical_ senses'. Hence, I'm fairly sure that though we '"feel" jealous', jealousy is always classed as an abstract noun. I'm finding that people disagree on the classification of 'hole', 'warmth' and 'music' - obviously, the physical senses are involved in identifying them, but how directly? Though we say we 'see' a hole, aren't we really seeing the immediate environment? A material presence seems to be involved in most definitions.

Comment: @Edwin: I was being a bit ironic with "as concrete as any other feeling or anything else detected by one of the senses". If reality is filtered through the senses, then we have no idea about what "concrete" means because we never encounter anything real, only sense data. And contemporary physicists tell us that what seems solid and concrete is merely something like dense energy: nothing is really solid--the electromagnetic bonds between atoms are stronger & more numerous. But that gets us into the depths of epistemology, which has nothing to do with English.

Comment: Yes, as a scientist, I'm aware of the 'how "real" is matter itself' debate. However, the terms 'abstract noun' and 'concrete noun' are used in semantics, and it would be a good idea to make sure everybody is using them the same way. From another website: Music is not a tangible, touchable, or palpable thing...however, we can perceive it with our ears--that is, we can sense it ... Is _music_ an abstract noun? (A) Music has no physical existence, therefore it is an abstract noun. (B) An abstract noun is one that escapes the five senses. Music does not fall into this category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A splurge is an act of splurging (spending a large amount of money) and a howler is something that is funny.

While you can't point to a splurge ("the splurge is beside the fridge" for example), it counts as a thing rather than abstract. And it is countable ("Three splurges in one week have left me without any money").

Abstract nouns, by contrast, would include *justice*, *art* or *hatred*. Even then they can have a concrete and abstract sense. *He was tortured by hatred* and *He was tortured by a hatred for his family* are both valid.

Comment: This answer shows confusion. _Hatred_ in both the above examples is abstract (unperceivable directly by physical senses) (though its manifestations may well be directly perceivable). There is a confusion here between mass vs count nouns and concrete vs abstract nouns. In any case, there is debate over a rigid definition of abstract nouns - do 'hole', 'absence', 'occasion' qualify? And saying ' "splurge" counts as a thing rather than [as] abstract' is terribly imprecise. Love is a many-splendored thing: we use the word 'thing' for concepts. I'm not sure who 'accepts' answers, or why.

Comment: @Edwin: "And saying '"splurge" counts as a thing rather than [as] abstract' is terribly imprecise." Yes, I agree, but linguistics isn't physics, math, or engineering. Terminology is only as precise as it needs to be -- _What's an adverb, really? And what's a verb tense? Or is that a sentence tense?_ Not even all hoary old professional linguists agree on what those terms mean. I think the folks who accept answers are users who feel that the answers they've accepted were at least **somewhat** helpful. Most language is metaphor anyway, so most speech is indirect & imprecise.

Comment: I've come across: 'Because there is a continuous spectrum between the totally abstract and the totally concrete, some words cannot be clearly called one or the other. So many words -- like _music_, _life_, _test_ cannot be labeled either _abstract_ **or** _concrete_.' at http://home.comcast.net/~tgeorges/write/les11.htm ; it will keep me happy as a working model. I can't seem to find an article dealing with the concrete - abstract problem in any great depth though - the subject is probably on the philosophical side of semantics, and articles here seem to be not too readily available.

Comment: I think it's better to think of *uses* or *senses* as abstract or concrete, not the words themselves. I also think it's unwise to assume that words when used in grammar correspond perfectly to how they are used elsewhere; think of all the dreadful advice to avoid the passive voice because it's "passive" or "denies agency" when it can lead to very active writing that underlines agency. Likewise here.

Comment: I'd like an agreed definition of the compound noun _abstract noun_, not a treatise on different registers where different polysemes of _abstract_ are used.